# How do i communicate between a widget and level blueprint?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I want to make a widget that has a restart button, but I have no idea how I'm supposed to tell the level blueprint that I clicked the button. And there's no way to get the player start object into the widget blueprint.

I've scraped the internet to no avail.

Comment: Check out https://dev.epicgames.com/community/learning/courses/LWv/unreal-engine-blueprint-communication/ypKl/unreal-engine-blueprint-communication-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible to talk to the level blueprint through a widget as far as i know. I'm not sure what you are trying to do as you could just execute the respawn code through the widget using on clicked. I would stay away from using the level blueprint as it is harder to cast to. I would use something like a game instance,player charater or even the game mode or an actor.
See unreal documentation...
https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/Casting/
https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/GetActorOfClass/